# Python rare IOError for mounted samba drive

Tags: python, samba, io

Procedure:

1. Mount samba drive (sudo mount.cifs ......)
2. Start jupyter notebook
3. Run a script that opens a bunch of matlab files, and does some heavy lifting on them afterwards
4. Leave the code run, come back a week later

90% of the time everything works no problem. But sometimes the code stops half way with an IOError

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda/envs/py36qt5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py in _open_file(file_like, appendmat)
     30     try:
---> 31         return open(file_like, 'rb'), True
     32     except IOError:

OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error:
```

Naturally, I've checked that the file it can't open does exist, and simply re-running the script will finish without errors (or, with small probability, crash on another file, which also exist)

I am aware that the remote samba drive connected to our our institute's LAN may experience short response delays. Maybe this is the cause.

**My questions are:**

1. How to diagnose the root of the problem
2. If it is indeed the case that my files can become temporarily inaccessible, can you suggest a wrapper script around the file loading command (*scipy.io.loadmat(filename)*) that would retry loading the file instead of crashing?

Answer (score 0):

If the OSError gets all the way back up to your code, catch it and retry.  If not, check that the file exists just before invoking matlab.  If it's matlab cranking away for hours without getting back to you, consider patching that file with a retry loop.  The source is right there, you can edit it if you have sufficient permissions.

Comment: It's IOError, I'm using python, not matlab. Matlab reader function is provided by scipy, so it is fine. My code is also fine, because error does not occur inside of it. Naturally, I can do try/catch inside a loop, but I wanted to ask professionals how to do this correctly. For example, I'm not sure how long I should wait between retries

Comment: Your question shows an OSError; the library catches an IOError. I'd suggest experimentation on the timing, something like a loop that waits one,  then two, then three seconds up to some limit like ten, and up to maybe 100 retries. The retry can check whether the file exists, and not even try the call until it does.  Log what happens.  You have nothing to lose, you're completely failing out now. And try to save some intermediate results if you can, so you don't have to start all over.